Ubuntu 24.04 - I've a 5.1 speaker setup, but the center and left rear channels are swapped, as well as subwoofer and rear right. How can I fix this?
I have dual booted Ubuntu 22.04 LTS and Ubuntu 24.04 LTS.
I have a 5.1 speaker setup.
In Ubuntu 22.04, when I do a speaker test, all of the channels are correct.
However, in Ubuntu 24.04 the center channel plays "Rear Left" and vice-versa.
Likewise the subwoofer plays "Rear Right" and vice-versa.
How can I fix the channels, so they are correct as in Ubuntu 22.04 ?

This is what I changed. It is not straightforward if you are a user but will be enough to get you googling
/etc/pulse/daemon.conf
You need to add or update
default-sample-channels = 6
default-channel-map = front-left,front-right,rear-left,rear-right,front-center,lfe
It is the default channel map sets the order.

Thank you both, but that did not solve the problem.

I tried changing the order of the channels, but nothing solved the problem.

Maybe you have a local config which overrides this. Not sure how experienced you are but there maybe another in ~/.config and of course you need to kill or reboot.
